# WPF : how to use the location to move the button when you click on it?

Tags: c#, wpf

Returns the Error CS1061 "Button" does not contain a definition of "Location", and could not find an available extension method "Location", taking the type "Button" as the first argument

Comment: Hi, please show the code, [edit] your question.

Comment: Also;, `Location` is not a property of a `Button`